# Installing Rbenv on a Mac - Beginner

Tags: ruby, git, installation, rbenv

I am new to Ruby and coding in general, and am trying to do a set of problems. However, I am unable to even get to the problems because the files I will be using require Rbenv and Bundler, and I cannot seem to install them on my Mac.

Can someone please give me a really simple explanation on how to correctly download the files (git ?) and install them via my terminal?

I have gone to github and downloaded the rbenv-master folder and saved it in a folder on my desktop. (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)
I can open my terminal and navigate to this folder.

Should I be saving something from the entire folder differently and loading that?
If so, what do I save it as and what do I type in my terminal to load it?

Once I do that, do I have to do anything else (use the require command??) to use this in my exercises?

Thanks for taking the time… I'll probably look back on this as a stupid questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just follow the homebrew install install instructions on the [rbenv github](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x) page.

You just may need to install homebrew first if you don't have it. Which is a one-line command found on the homebrew homepage.